# Music stops playing in bacground

Tags: music

it's not a big problem but i'ts annoying me quite a lot because when I'm listening not music using Rhythembox it' stops playing after about half a minute of playing. When I'm using vlc it does the same but gives a input/output error, so it's not Rhythembox that causes the problem. Tried somethings but nothing works. And just to add, streamed music (in browser) works perfectly fine.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post the error VLC gives?

Comment: Is this error on VLC/Rythmbox when you're listening the same music file?